# What is the correctly derived adjectival form, if any, of apothecary?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

What is the proper adjectival form, if any, of ***apothecary***?

My best guess is '*apothecal*', although my resources have not found a definitive answer one way or the other.

For example:

> Jordan opened the package he had brought from the apothecary.  It had a clear *apothecal* smell.

Comment: How about _apotithenary_? _Apothecary_ comes from the Greek word for 'storehouse', which is made up of _apo-_ 'away', plus _tithenai_ 'to put'. There appear to have been some syllables haplogized away in _apothecary_, but that need not have happened to an adjective. In any event, _apotithenary_ can't possibly means anything else.

Comment: Also @JohnLawler Although the etymology relates to a storehouse, the current usage of the term is to a person or his "office" (i.e., practice/ vocation) in pharmacy. As such, its adjectival use with smell is bound to have hilarious outcomes.

Comment: @John, no haplology involved—it's just based on the unreduplicated root, rather than the reduplicated present stem. (Not sure exactly what the _-k-_ suffix is, but it appears to be structurally identical to ‘theme’, with its more familiar _*-men-_ suffix.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the etymology of *apothecary* relates to a 'storehouse,' the current usage of the term is with reference to a **person** or his "**office**" (i.e., practice/ vocation) in pharmacy.

As such, its adjectival use with *smell* is bound to have hilarious outcomes.

However, should one insist on using such an expression, merely making an adjectival 'use' of the noun itself should be acceptable.

> It had a clear apothecary smell.

Luckily, the word already sounds like an adjective, too.

---

[**apothecarial**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apothecarial)

> adj. Characteristic of an apothecary

Walton:

> Colard, a barber-surgeon, illustrated the **apothecarial** duties that a surgeon might perform when he wrote, I bequethe to John my sone all my instruments of ...

Roberts:

> Inside, you'll sense a curious **apothecarial smell**, traced to the shelves lined with old pots and jars (labeled in Latin).

'Mama Earth' on Infobarrel:

> Gin is derived predominantly from juniper berries, and mixed with herbs and spices to create its strange **apothecarial smell**.

Comment: Odd fixation on the "person" component.  you could say the same thing about "doctoral", which while cumbersome has a similar meaning.  ("lawyerly smell", too, now that I think about it...)

Comment: @DougM Agree with the rest of the comment, though the 'person' aspect is no fixation at all. The brick-and-mortar sense of *storehouse* is now archaic.